# if i press F5, input value not reset 1, but if i press ctrl+f5 or press Enter in url search bar, input value reset 1? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

first, i add number is 5 in input, when i press F5 refresh get result for:
[image]

why input value not reset 1, still is 5?

sencond, when i press ctrl+F5 or press Enter in url search bar, the input value reset 1? 
[image]

this is my code:

```
var $plus = $('.plus'), //add
    $reduce = $('.reduce'), //reduce
    $all_sum = $('.sum'); //input

$plus.click(function() {
    var $inputVal = $(this).prev('input'),
        //input value
        $count = parseInt($inputVal.val()) + 1,

        $obj = $(this).parents('.amount_box').find('.reduce'),


        $priceTotalObj = $(this).parents('.order_lists').find('.sum_price'), 

        //singlePrice
        $price = $(this).parents('.order_lists').find('.price').html(), 

        //singlePrice*count
        $priceTotal = ($count * $price.substring(1)).toFixed(2);
    //console.log($price.substring(1));

    //数量加运费
    $singleTransPrice = $(this).parents('.order_lists').find('.trans_single_price').html(); //单件运费
    $transTotalObj = $(this).parents('.order_lists').find('.trans_total_price'); //单件商品总运费
    $transTotalPrice = ($count * $singleTransPrice.substring(1)).toFixed(2); //运费
    console.log($transTotalPrice)

    $inputVal.val($count);
    $priceTotalObj.html('￥' + $priceTotal);
    $transTotalObj.html('￥' + $transTotalPrice);
    if ($inputVal.val() > 1 && $obj.hasClass('reSty')) {
        $obj.removeClass('reSty');
    }
    totalMoney();
});
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between f5 and ctrl+f5?

Comment: ctrl+f5 and Enter make a http request?@epascarello

Comment: try `<form autocomplete="off" .....>.......</form>`

Comment: thank you very much@plonknimbuzz

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `<form autocomplete="off" .....>.......</form>` to prevent form filled by cache value